# Saving offsets in Spark Structured Streaming Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, offset, spark-structured-streaming

Using spark strcutured streaming for batch queries, how do I read a certain batch, process them and save the offsets so that a subsequent run of the job starts consuming from where it left off the first time?